# Relation between the connectivity and the minimum degree of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove that for every graph $G$, (a) $κ(G) ≤ δ(G)$; (b)   if $δ(G)≥n−2,$ then $κ(G)=δ(G).$

Here $κ(G)$ is the connectivity, which is the minimum size of a cut set of $G$. And  $δ(G)$ is the minimum degree of $G$.

I have part (a) I'm having a hard time with part (b).

Comment: What is $\kappa(G)$? Is $\delta(G)$ the minimum degree of $G$?

Comment: κ(G) is the connectivity, which is the minimum size of a cut set of G. And yes δ(G) is the minimum degree of G.

Comment: did you read my answer?

Answer (score 2):

$\kappa(G)$ is presumably the vertex connectivity of $G$.

Suppose $\delta(G)=n-1$. Then no matter what vertices you take the graph will remain connexted.

Suppose $\delta(G)=n-2$. What does a graph with minimum degree $n-2$ look like? What does the complement look like? it has connected components with $2$ or $1$ vertices. Therefore if you take vertices away from $G$ the complement will always remain disconnected unless you remove $n-2$ vertices. Since the complement of a disconnected graph is connected we conclude we need to remove $n-2$ vertices to make $G$ disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that for any graph G:

a) k(G)≤δ(G)
Proof: Let G be a graph of order n and let v∈V(G), be a vertex in G such that deg⁡(v)=δ(G). Then we can disconnect v from G by removing δ(G) edges. Hence the connectivity of G must be smaller or equal to δ(G).
b) If δ(G)≥n-2, then k(G)=δ(G)
 
Proof: Let G be a graph of order n such that δ(G)≥n-2. If δ(G)=n-1 then G is complete and by definition k(G)=n-1= δ(G). Note that δ(G) cannot be bigger then n-1 for simple graphs, so we are left with the case for δ(G)=n-2. Let S={v<sub>1</sub>,u<sub>2</sub>,...,v<sub>n-2</sub> } be a subset of V(G) such that k(G-S)=0. Suppose we can remove one vertex from S, and still have G-S be disconnected. But then |V(G-S)|=n-(n-3)=3, and the lowest degree for a vertex in G-S is δ(G-S)=δ(G)-|S|=n-2-(n-3)=1, so it must be connected (draw a graph to prove this to yourself). Therefore, if δ(G)=n-2 then it must be the case that k(G)=δ(G)=n-2